# Nav with two dynamic elements + border of first

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've made an Image of what I want to archieve.
The logo resizes on different screen resolutions and the actual navigation container is just as long as the `<li>'s`.

The bottom border needs to reach to the lower left edge of the logo.

The logo itself has a shadow below, so the border cant be full width.

[image: visualization]

What I've got so far is that the nav itself has a border which then only reaches to the last `<li>`

This is a quick mockup:

http://jsfiddle.net/2x6hddv8/

Comment: Post your code in your question please.

Comment: this could help - just gives you an idea: http://jsfiddle.net/mXLgF/1060/

Answer (score 0):

Here's most of it -- they just called my flight!

http://jsfiddle.net/8k45z7nL/

I'd avoid the `skew` for maximum browser compatibility.